# Sorter Function in List never called

Tags: qooxdoo

I tried to Implement the `qx.ui.list.core.IListDelegate.sorter` function in a `qx.data.controller.List`. I set the Delegate of the controller with the specific sort Function. The Problem is, that the sorter Function is never been called.

```js
var list = new qx.ui.form.List();

var rawData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  rawData.push(i);
}
var data = new qx.data.Array(rawData);

var listController = new qx.data.controller.List(data, list);
listController.setDelegate({
    sorter : function(a, b) {
      console.log("test");
        if (Number(a.getLabel()) > Number(b.getLabel())) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (Number(a.getLabel()) < Number(b.getLabel())) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
});

// Document is the application root
var doc = this.getRoot();

doc.add(list,
{
  left : 100,
  top  : 50
});
```

Here is the example in the qx Playground: tinyurl.com/y6udac8g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qx.ui.list.core.IListDelegate.sorter` is used to configure `qx.ui.list.List` and not `qx.ui.form.List`.

Check the [example](http://www.qooxdoo.org/devel/api/#qx.ui.list.List) in the documentation to use the `sorter` function of the `qx.ui.list.List` class

```js
//create the model data
var rawData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {
 rawData[i] = "Item No " + i;
}
var model = qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel(rawData);

//create the list
var list = new qx.ui.list.List(model);

//configure the lists's behavior
var delegate = {
  sorter : function(a, b) {
    return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
  }
};
list.setDelegate(delegate);

//Pre-Select "Item No 20"
list.getSelection().push(model.getItem(20));

//log selection changes
list.getSelection().addListener("change", function(e) {
  this.debug("Selection: " + list.getSelection().getItem(0));
}, this);
```